# MonacaでAjax通信を行い外部サーバーにあるphp(MySQLを使用するために)を使っています。 phpを使ってデータベース内の中身を表示させたい

Tags: javascript, php, monaca, json, ajax

MonacaでAjax通信を行い外部サーバーにあるphp(MySQLを使用するために)を使っています。
phpを使ってデータベース内の中身を表示させたいです。Ajax通信を行いJsonで受け取っているのですがうまくいかないのでMonaca側とphp側で何かあればアドバイスをお願いします。

「Monaca側」実行結果→console.logでjsが表示，エラーアラートの発生。

```
//口コミのボタンを押すとページ遷移と更新を同時に行う 
function anime1() {
    app.slidingMenu.setMainPage('page1.html', {closeMenu: true});
}

function anime2() {
    console.log("jh");
      // Ajaxで～.phpを利用してDBにアクセス
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            scriptCharset: 'utf-8',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            url: サーバーにある～.phpファイル名

       }).done(function(data){
        // DBから引っ張ってきたデータを料理名を選択するoptionにセット
         console.log("投稿完了！");
         // for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
         // $('.food_name_box').append($('<option>').html(data[i]["japanese"]).val(data[i]["id"]));
         // }


       }).fail(function(data){
           alert('error!!!');
           //console.log("error");
       });
}
```

「php側」

```
<?php

//DB接続
require_once('config.php');

// $text1 = $_POST["sender_name"];
// $text2 = $_POST["sender_mail_address"];
// $text3 = $_POST["contact_body"];
// $text4 = $_POST["time"];


$result=$pdo->prepare("select*from 13DB066_test");
$result->execute();
$result_value=$result->fetchAll();

header('Content-type: application/json');
header('Content-type: html');
echo json_encode( $result_value );
//var_dump($result_value);
```

Answer (score 2):

JSON と JSONP をお間違えではありませんか？

参考 http://tsujimotter.info/2013/01/03/jsonp/

`dataType` に `jsonp` が指定されていますが、PHP側で出力しているのはただのJSONです。

よって `dataType: 'json'` と指定すべきですし、スクリプトとして読み込む際のエンコーディングを指定する `scriptCharset` も不要です。

またPHP側で `header('Content-type: ...')` を二回実行しているのは何故でしょうか。見たところ後者が余分だと思います（そもそも `html` は正しいMediaTypeではありませんが）。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
ご指摘があった個所のMoanaca側のdataTypeをjsonpからjsonになおしてみました。
Monaca側実行結果，console.log("投稿完了！")で投稿完了が出てきました！

次に出力したいのですがどういった形で行えばよいでしょうか？document.writeなど使用するのでしょうか？

Comment: @おじゃる 画面の一部に出力したいのでしょうから、特定のタグの中身を書き換える、なんてことをするわけですが…いずれにしてもAjaxとは独立した話なので、新しく質問を投稿してくださいね

Comment: ＠unarist　Ajaxとは独立した話になるのですね！新しく投稿します！ありがとうございます。